three.js - 'Interleaved' Render from both perspective and orthogonal scene
I'm trying to conditionally render from a perspective and ortho scene & camera together.
Eg, imagine an old school computer game where there are 2d sprites positioned on top of a 3d scene BUT the some of the 2d sprites sit 'behind' some of the 3d objects. Therefore a straight '3d then 2d' render isn't the answer. Is there a correct 'phrase' that is commonly understood for this approach?
Examples:

Working scene without interleaving the 2d planes over the 3d balls
My failed attempt at forcibly rendering programmatically

Example 1 - Working scene without interleaving the 2d planes over the 3d balls


// Create renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true })
renderer.setSize(600, 600)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
renderer.sortObjects = false

// Perspective Scene Setup
const scenePerspective = new THREE.Scene()
const perspectiveCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 600 / 600, 0.1, 1000)
perspectiveCamera.position.set(19, 10, 12)
const orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(perspectiveCamera, renderer.domElement)


// Orthographic Scene Setup
const sceneOrtho = new THREE.Scene()
const orthoCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(600 / -2, 600 / 2, 600 / 2, 600 / -2, 0.1, 1000)
orthoCamera.position.set(0, 0, 10)
orthoCamera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)

// Create 3d spheres in perspective scene - renderOrder 0,2,4,6,8
const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32)
for (let i = -2; i <= 2; i++) {
  const renderOrder = (i + 2) * 2
  const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color( renderOrder / 8, 0.0, 0.8 ),
    depthTest: false // ? Ideally, I'd like to keep this true?!
  })
  const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial)
  sphere.position.set(i * 3, 0, 0)
  sphere.renderOrder = renderOrder
  //console.log("sphere render order", sphere.renderOrder)
  scenePerspective.add(sphere)
}

// Create 2d planes in orthographic scene - renderOrder 1,3,5,7
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(30, 30)
for (let i = -1; i <= 2; i++) {
  const renderOrder = (i + 2) * 2 - 1
  const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color( 0, 0.8, renderOrder / 8 ),
    depthTest: true // ?
  })
  const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial)
  plane.position.set(i * 50 - 10, i * -40 + 10, 0)
  plane.renderOrder = renderOrder
  
  sceneOrtho.add(plane)
}

// Animate and render both scenes
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  orbitControls.update()

  // Render Perspective Scene
  renderer.clear() // Clear buffer
  renderer.render(scenePerspective, perspectiveCamera)
  
  // Render Orthographic Scene on top
  renderer.autoClear = false
  renderer.clearDepth(); // Clear depth buffer to render on top
  renderer.render(sceneOrtho, orthoCamera);
}

// Start animation
animate()
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>



Example 2 - My failed attempt at forcibly rendering programmatically


// Create renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true })
renderer.setSize(600, 600)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
renderer.sortObjects = false

// Perspective Scene Setup
const scenePerspective = new THREE.Scene()
const perspectiveCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 600 / 600, 0.1, 1000)
perspectiveCamera.position.set(19, 10, 12)
const orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(perspectiveCamera, renderer.domElement)


// Orthographic Scene Setup
const sceneOrtho = new THREE.Scene()
const orthoCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(600 / -2, 600 / 2, 600 / 2, 600 / -2, 0.1, 1000)
orthoCamera.position.set(0, 0, 10)
orthoCamera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)

// Create 3d spheres in perspective scene - renderOrder 0,2,4,6,8
const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32)
for (let i = -2; i <= 2; i++) {
  const renderOrder = (i + 2) * 2
  const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color( renderOrder / 8, 0.0, 0.8 ),
    depthTest: false // ? Ideally, I'd like to keep this true?!
  })
  const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial)
  sphere.position.set(i * 3, 0, 0)
  sphere.renderOrder = renderOrder
  //console.log("sphere render order", sphere.renderOrder)
  scenePerspective.add(sphere)
}

// Create 2d planes in orthographic scene - renderOrder 1,3,5,7
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(30, 30)
for (let i = -1; i <= 2; i++) {
  const renderOrder = (i + 2) * 2 - 1
  const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color( 0, 0.8, renderOrder / 8 ),
    depthTest: true // ?
  })
  const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial)
  plane.position.set(i * 50 - 10, i * -40 + 10, 0)
  plane.renderOrder = renderOrder
  
  sceneOrtho.add(plane)
}
function collectObjects(scene, camera) {
  const objects = []
  scene.traverse(function (object) {
    if (object.isMesh) {
      objects.push({
        object: object,
        camera: camera,
        renderOrder: object.renderOrder
      })
    }
  })
  return objects
}

// Animate and render both scenes
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  orbitControls.update()

  // Collect all objects from both scenes
  const allObjects = [
    ...collectObjects(scenePerspective, perspectiveCamera),
    ...collectObjects(sceneOrtho, orthoCamera)
  ];

  // Sort all objects by their renderOrder
  allObjects.sort((a, b) => a.renderOrder - b.renderOrder)

  // Render all objects in the correct order
  renderer.clear()
  renderer.autoClear = false

  allObjects.forEach(({ object, camera }) => {
    renderer.renderBufferDirect(camera, null, object.geometry, object.material, object, null)
  })

}

// Start animation
animate()
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>



Any tips?!
